# Writing scraped data to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've been stuck trying to transfer the data that I scraped to a csv file. Here is my code:

```
import requests, bs4, csv, sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
url = 'http://www.constructeursdefrance.com/resultat/?dpt=01'

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
links = []

for div in soup.select('.link'):
    link = div.a.get('href')
    links.append(link)
for i in links:
    url2 = i
    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
    for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
        data = each.text, each.next_sibling
    with open('french.csv', 'wb') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(data)
```

the output says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_new_project.py", line 23, in <module>
writer.writerows(data)
csv.Error: sequence expected
```

But I am trying to put tuples into the csv file, and as long as I know csv accepts tuples and lists. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atirag is correct, but you have another issue which is that your with call to open the output file is nested within a for loop. So if there is more than one link, the file will be overwritten each time and the output will not be what you expect.   I think this should generate the output you intend:

```
for div in soup.select('.link'):
    link = div.a.get('href')
    links.append(link)

with open("french.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in links:
        res2 = requests.get(i)
        soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
        for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
            writer.writerow([each.text, each.next_sibling])
```

Comment: yes it worked! did not know that it can be done this way, lessoned learned. can you explain how [each.text, each.next_sibling] works in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
        data = each.text, each.next_sibling
```

to this

```
data=[]
for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
        data.append((each.text, each.next_sibling))
```

your data variable was one tuple not a list of tuples. The above code creates a list of tuples.

Other solution is this (mind the indentation)

```
data = []
for i in links:
    url2 = i
    res2 = requests.get(url2)
    soup2 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text, 'html.parser')
    for each in soup2.select('li > strong'):
        data.append((each.text, each.next_sibling))
with open('french.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: he still has the problem of his output file being overwritten each time his for i in links loop iterates

Comment: This is great man, but somehow my output csv only gets the last piece of scraped information. What happened to the other data? I'm not sure what went wrong with the code

Comment: @PeterLin Yep, I see the issue. Kevin's solution should work fine then.